# IF condition in where clause in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, if-statement, where-clause

I need to write the if condition in the `where` clause of SQL where I wanted to define that if one column is null then search in another column in a row. I have used union but it's making the query slow to execute, so help me write this statement in the proper way.

This is the code I have right now:

```
SELECT * 
FROM ACCOUNT 
WHERE (IF ACCOUNTID IS NULL THEN REF_ACC_ID = 12 ELSE ACCOUNTID = 12)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `isnull` built in function in sql server

like below link

[w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_isnull.asp)

you can write this code for solve your problem

```
SELECT * 
FROM ACCOUNT 
WHERE isnull(ACCOUNTID ,REF_ACC_ID ) = 12
```

Comment: SQL is not accepting these syntax REF_ACC_ID =12 ???? i have tried earlier and now also its giving syntax error

Comment: @JayMewada yes its true , i change my answer that is ok

Comment: thank you it worked thanks a lot otherwise i was introducing a common field to fetch data